# Stored Procedure unused parameter show error

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures

The error being received is:

> Procedure or function SPCustomerDetails expects parameter '@address', which was not supplied.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Procedure or function 'SPCustomerDetails' expects parameter '@address', which was not supplied.

My stored procedure is:

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPCustomerDetails]
(
@id varchar,
@title varchar(50),
@fname varchar(50),
@Lname varchar(50),
@mob varchar(50),
@email varchar(50),
@password varchar(50),
@address varchar(50),
@altemail varchar(50),
@gender varchar(50),
@dob varchar(50),
@city varchar(50),
@country varchar(50),
@state varchar(50),
@checked varchar(50),
@opr varchar(50)

)
as
begin
    if @opr='BTNNEW'
    INSERT INTO TblCustomer_Details
    (FName,LName,Email,Password,Contact_No,checked)
     VALUES
     (@fname,@Lname,@email,@password,@mob,@checked)

     else if @opr='BTNUPDATE'
     Update  TblCustomer_Details 
     set
        Title=@title,
        FName=@fname,
        LName=@Lname,
        Email=@email,
        alt_Email=@altemail,
        Address=@address,
        Password=@password,
        Gender=@gender,
        DOB=@dob,
        Contact_No=@mob,
        Country=@country,
        State=@state,
        City=@city
        where 
        Cust_ID=@id

    else if @opr='BTNDELETE'
    delete TblCustomer_Details 
    from TblCustomer_Details
    where
    Cust_ID=@id
```

To execute procedure:

```
con.ExeQry(" exec SPCustomerDetails '" + fname.Text.Trim() + "',N'" + 
  lname.Text.Trim() + "',N'" + pemail.Text.Trim() + "',N'" + 
  cpassword.Text.Trim() + "',N'" + mobile.Text.Trim() + "',N'" + 
  offers.Checked + "','" + opr.ToUpper() + "'");
```

Comment: Your proc has 16 mandatory parameters, where you only seem to be passing about 7. Also, parameterize!

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question, you've just posted an error and some code; even if it seems unnecessary, it is still polite.

Comment: but i want pass only 7 parameter at frist time then what i can do?

Comment: so pass null if you not req that parameter

Answer (score 0):

Try this technique :-

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE ProcName

    @Parameter1 VARCHAR (100) = NULL
AS

/* check for the NULL */ 
if (@Parameter1 IS NULL)
BEGIN
    /* your code*/

END

/* In Query*/
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Column = @Parameter1
```

Comment: Can you explain how this helps answer the original question?

Comment: @Adrian Wragg He just wants to pass few parameters and with above technique I think Its easy to pass only the required ones.

Answer (score 0):

```
con.ExeQry(" exec SPCustomerDetails '" + fname.Text.Trim() + "',N'" + lname.Text.Trim() + "',N'" + pemail.Text.Trim() + "',N'" + cpassword.Text.Trim() + "',N'" + mobile.Text.Trim() + "',N'" + offers.Checked + "','" + opr.ToUpper() + "'");
```

the string which you gave in con.ExeQry is shown like this

exec SPCustomerDetails 'fname',N'lname',N'mobile',N'pemail',N'pwd',N'offers','opr'

its throws sql exception

Here i take fname.Text.Trim() =fname,lname.Text.Trim()=lname......

it shoud be like this

exec SPCustomerDetails 'fname',’Nlname',’Npemail',’Npwd',’Nmovile',’Noffers','opr'

you said that you are passing 7 parameters at first time.so at first time pass NULL where you dont want to pass parameter like this

exec SPCustomerDetails 
NULL,NULL,'fname',’Nlname',NULL,’Npemail',’Npwd',NULL,’Nmovile',’Noffers',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'opr'

i just write the query in sqlquery style convert this into your Asp.net style

like
 con.ExeQry(" exec SPCustomerDetails .....

You gave different order while parameter passing you should give the parameters in the same way as you mentioned in the stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you want certain fields to be declared as optional. Unfortunately, with the code given you appear to be assuming that SQL will "work out" what you mean based on the names of the variables you're passing in to your call to `SPCustomerDetails`.

Your stored procedure call will merely resolve to:

```
exec SPCustomerDetails 'Bob', N'Smith', N'bob@sample.com', N'hunter2',
    N'07111 1234', N'True', 'True'
```

which will be passed in to populate the first seven parameters; the eighth, `@address`, will be the first to have no value hence the error you're seeing.

If you wish to have default (and, therefore, optional) values in your stored procedure call, you can declare this within the procedure definition by putting the default value after the parameter; for example:

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPCustomerDetails]
(
    @id varchar,
    @title varchar(50) = null,
    @fname varchar(50),
    ...
```

will not require the `@title` field to be passed in. You will also need to alter your stored procedure call to populate the individual parameters directly. Your database call would need to read:

```
exec SPCustomerDetails @fname = 'Bob',
                       @lname = 'Smith',
                       @email = 'bob@sample.com'
```

or, in code:

```
con.ExeQry(" exec SPCustomerDetails @fname = '" + fname.Text.Trim() + "'," +
                                  " @lname = '" + lname.Text.Trim() + "'," +
                                  " @email = '" + email.Text.Trim() + "'," +
...
```

That said, there are two other issues with this code that should also be addressed, fixes for which are outside the scope of this answer:

1. You should parameterise your stored procedure calls, rather than coding everything directly into a single string; the code as-is leaves you wide open to SQL Injection attacks.
2. Based on the code I can see, you are taking a password straight from the user interface and storing it in the database. You should *never* store a password in plain text; it should, at a mininum, be hashed and salted.